# php get all values from database and return to xml field?

Tags: php, mysql, xml, domdocument

i need some help with my app . I have this code :

realtime.php

```
$jogador = Jogador::getSaldoJogadorByEmail($email);
$premio = Premio::getValorPremioByTipo($tipo);
$participante = Participantes::getATotalParticipantesFromPA1();
$doc = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$action = $doc->createElement('action');
$action = $doc->appendChild($action);
$jogador = $doc->createElement('jogador1', $jogador);
$jogador = $action->appendChild($jogador);
$premio = $doc->createElement('premio1', $premio);
$premio = $action->appendChild($premio);
$participante = $doc->createElement('participante1', $participante);
$participante = $action->appendChild($participante);
$output = $doc->saveXML();
header("Content-type: application/xml");
echo $output;
```

and i have this function that is only p+assing one value instead of passing all the content of the database :

```
static function getTotalParticipantesFromPA1(){
    $db = new mysqli("localhost","******","****","participantes");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM premioacumulado1";
    $result = $db->query($query);
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ){
        while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $id = $row['id'];
        $username = $row['username'];
        $m = "ID: " . $id . " " . "User: " . $username . "\n";
        return $m;
        } 
    }else{
        $db->close();
        return NULL;
    }
    
}
```

all other fields are working in realtime , but this one is only getting one value from the database ...

how to get all the values from the database?

Edited - 22-05-2022

```
static function getTotalParticipantesFromPA1(){
    $db = new mysqli("localhost","*****","*****","participantes");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM premioacumulado1";
    $result = $db->query($query);
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ){
        while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $id = $row['id'];
        $username = $row['username'];
        $m = "ID: " . $id . " " . "User: " . $username . "\n";
        
        }
        return $m; // if i put it here it only returns the last value in the data base .
    }else{
        $db->close();
        return NULL;
    }
    
}

static function getTotalParticipantesFromPA1(){
    $db = new mysqli("localhost","*****","*****","participantes");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM premioacumulado1";
    $result = $db->query($query);
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ){
        while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $id = $row['id'];
        $username = $row['username'];
        $m = "ID: " . $id . " " . "User: " . $username . "\n";
        echo $m;// if i do a echo i get an error in the xml $participante variable(realtime.php) , maybe convert it here so it can take the result , but how ?
        } 
    }else{
        $db->close();
        return NULL;
    }
    
}
```

here is the script Js :

```
function getRealTime(){
  //retrieve the DOM objects to place content
  var domjogador1 = document.getElementById("saldo");
  var dompremiovaloracu1 = document.getElementById("valorActualPremioAcu1");
  var domparticipantes1 = document.getElementById("areaParticipantesAcu1");
  

  //send the get request to retrieve the data
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("GET", "realtimegame.php", true);
  request.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){
      //parse the xml document to get each data element
      var xmldoc = request.responseXML;

      var xmljogador1 = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("jogador1")[0];
      var jogador1 = xmljogador1.childNodes[0].nodeValue;

      var xmlpremio1 = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("premio1")[0];
      var premio1 = xmlpremio1.childNodes[0].nodeValue;

      var xmlparticipante1 = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("participante1")[0];
      var participante1 = xmlparticipante1.childNodes[0].nodeValue;

     

      domjogador1.innerHTML = jogador1;
      dompremiovaloracu1.innerHTML = premio1;
      domparticipantes1.innerHTML = participante1;
      
    }
  };
  request.send();
}
```

Comment: `return` in your `while` loop will exit/break on the first iteration of the loop. Create an array with all the values you need

Comment: can someone help with an example pls

Comment: i try  using array , i try using echo instead of return but i allway get errors . i have a test file and i can get all the data from the database , i just cant get it to work with the xml ...

Comment: @brombeer can you pls explain in more detail ?? im getting so frustrated ... :(

Comment: Really???? nobody can solve this ? ?

Comment: @brombeer ,OMG .... thanks my friend , your where right all along , thanks a lot . Now that i got it  i see that it wasn't very hard . I'm just new in this and i don't have many experience . Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

here is the function that works , now with a more pretty result:

```
static function getBTotalParticipantesFromPA1(){
    $db = new mysqli("localhost","root","","participantes");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM premioacumulado1";
    $result = $db->query($query);
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $s = "<br />";
    $data1 = array();
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ){
        do{
            $data1[] = $row['username'] . " " . $row['id'] . "&#xA;";
            
            
        }while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC));
        return json_encode($data1);
    }else{
        $db->close();
        return NULL;
    }
    
}
```

I still wanted to print out something a little more pretty for end user to see . with this i get the line break in each value , but i still wanted to remove the "," from the output ... if anyone has something that can be used better then this please post it , thanks .